# Use a decorator (or some other pattern) on an object instance to generate a class

Tags: python, decorator

I can see multiple roadblocks to making this work, and it may well be impossible, but I thought I'd at least ask...

So, I have a class `AbstractEnumeratedConstantsGroup` that, unsurprisingly, when subclassed creates an object that represents a group of enumerated constants (ex `FLAVORS` with values `('VANILLA', 'CHOCOLATE', 'STRAWBERRY')` where `FLAVORS[0]` returns `'VANILLA'`, `FLAVORS[1]` returns `'CHOCOLATE'`, `FLAVORS.VANILLA` returns `0`, `FLAVORS.CHOCOLATE` returns `1`, etc) it uses a metaclass and some other footwork so that all that is required to create a new constants group is:

```
class FLAVORS(AbstractEnumeratedConstantsGroup):
    _constants = ('VANILLA', 'CHOCOLATE', 'STRAWBERRY')
FLAVORS = FLAVORS()
```

I'd like to reduce it further to:

```
@enumerated_constants_group
FLAVORS = ('VANILLA', 'CHOCOLATE', 'STRAWBERRY')
```

The problems I don't know how to get past are:

  1. No good way to get the label name for the object from the defining scope from the decorator code
  2. Can't decorate something that isn't a class, method, or function

I've considered using a factory/builder, but what I don't like about that is that it requires duplication of the group name in the code, or that the groups have unhelpful `__name__` values (which are used in `__repr__` and `__str__`).  Ex:

```
FLAVOR = enumerated_constants_group('FLAVOR', ('VANILLA', 'CHOCOLATE', 'STRAWBERRY'))
```

or

```
FLAVOR = enumerated_constants_group(('VANILLA', 'CHOCOLATE', 'STRAWBERRY'))
# FLAVOR.__name__ becomes some unfriendly machine-generated string
```

As an alternative to the decorator idea, would it be possible to reference the calling scope (through introspection or from implicitly passing it to the function) from a factory method such that calling the method would insert the newly created object in to the calling namespace with the given name?  Ex:

```
enumerated_constants_group('FLAVOR', ('VANILLA', 'CHOCOLATE', 'STRAWBERRY'))
# I could now reference FLAVOR in any arbitrary scope that the method was called from
```

Is there anything I can do to achieve what I want?  Are there other approaches I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no general way to affect what happens when you assign to a bare name (as in `FLAVORS = ('VANILLA', 'CHOCOLATE', 'STRAWBERRY')`).  So what you want is not possible.

That said, you could write a metaclass that replaces the returned class with an instance of itself, so that you don't need your last `FLAVORS = FLAVORS(...)` line in your first example.  The class definition itself would suffice to create the object.

Comment: I ended up doing this.  It does have the side-effect that I can't subclass any concrete constant classes, which is unfortunate, but one step a a time.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/413486/

It allows you to write code like this:

```
>>> from enum import enum
>>> FLAVORS = enum('VANILLA', 'CHOCOLATE', 'STRAWBERRY')
>>> print FLAVORS
enum (VANILLA, CHOCOLATE, STRAWBERRY)
>>> print FLAVORS.VANILLA
VANILLA
>>> f = FLAVORS.CHOCOLATE
>>> f in FLAVORS
True
>>> for f in FLAVORS:
...     print f
...
VANILLA
CHOCOLATE
STRAWBERRY
```

Comment: Yeah, that shares a lot with what I cooked up myself.  I think I have to go along the lines of what @BrenBarn said in his answer.  I'll have to look over the comparison code in this example to see if I missed anything though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As an intermediate step, you could do

```
FLAVORS = type("FLAVORS",
               (AbstractEnumeratedConstantsGroup,),
               {_constants = ('VANILLA', 'CHOCOLATE', 'STRAWBERRY')})()
```

which leads to a fake decorator

```
def enumerated_constants_group(*args):
    AECG=AbstractEnumeratedConstantsGroup
    t = type(args[0], (AECG,), dict(_constants=args[1:]))
    return t()

FLAVORS = enumerated_constants_group('FLAVORS', 'VANILLA', 'CHOCOLATE', 'STRAWBERRY')
```

Comment: The name is important, actually.  `__repr__` and `__str__` use `__name__`, which makes these objects much easier to work with when debugging and the like.

Comment: Modified so that the first argument to `e_c_g` is the name of the type; I think that's as clever as I get :) But now this is really just an implementation of the factory function you already considered.

Answer (score 0):

Besides function/method decorators, you have also class decorators (at least they were there in python 2.4), see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/

Anyway, I'm not sure this is what you need.

I would go with the factory class that gets (type, values) as args.

One note: if your code is just like this, and AbstractEnumeratedConstantsGroup doesn't add any functionality, why don't you just use tuples?

You could define a constants.py module with the following content:

```
FLAVOURS = ('VANILLA', 'CHOCOLATE', 'STRAWBERRY')
PETS = ('DOG', 'CAT', 'FISH')
```

and then use those tuples from your code:

```
import constants
for pet in constants.PETS:
    print 'I have a ', pet
```

Comment: The base class provides an easier to use interface than a tuple.  Rather than `PETS.index('DOG')`, you can get the same result with just `PETS.DOG`.  It also does other things like customized iteration and membership testing, and it actually automatically builds the members in to a special enumerated value type that overrides equality and other checks.

Answer (score 0):

How about named tuples. http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Comment: I actually implemented a similar thing before using namedtuples (requirements from a guy who's principle design guideline was "if it's not like Java, it's not done right," *shudder*).  Thing is, you still have to do some wonky footwork to map bidirectionally (given key get value, given value get key).  Every solution other than the AS one or what I did does some part of the pattern well, but not another.

Comment: Point taken. Wouldn't this require a new type which can look-up for values in a bidirectional manner as opposed to creating dynamic types. I have been developing in python only for a few months, so I might be missing the point.

Comment: Yup. :)  The abstract base class actually transforms that list of constants in to a series of objects that can do that.